# Gradle sync fails with Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am using android studio 4.2 and I live in Iran so I can't access google() and jcenter() repositories due to sanctions. I was looking for alternative ways for a week now and using vpn or any ip changer is not working because of Google's new location finding algorithm

installed Gradle locally via distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

but ended up with this error

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2/gradle-7.2.pom
>
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the
> repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to
> adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change to gradle-7.1-all

Comment: It is not about gradle version the dl.google.com site is unreachable